# Concatenate 2 dates in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wanted to concatenate 2 dates below but I am getting an error that

```
Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The data types date and varchar are incompatible in the add operator.
```

My Code is:

```
SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, -7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) [WeekStart],
    DATEADD(DAY, -1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) [WeekEnd],
    (DATEADD(DAY, -7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) + ' to ' +  DATEADD(DAY, -1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))) as Week
```

Expected result:

```
WeekStart   WeekEnd      WeekRange
2015-09-27  2015-10-03   2015-09-27 to 2015-10-03
```

---

#### Resolved

[Resolved] used convert:

```
SELECT  DATEADD(DAY, -7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) [WeekStart],
    DATEADD(DAY, -1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) [WeekEnd],
    convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(DAY, -7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)),110) + ' TO ' +  convert(varchar(10),DATEADD(DAY, -1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)),110) as Week
```

Comment: Have you tried the `CONVERT` function?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `convert()` with 121:

```
select (left(convert(varchar(255), WeekStart, 121), 10) + ' - ' +
        left(convert(varchar(255), WeekEnd, 121), 10)
       ) as WeekRange
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) [WeekStart]
      ,DATEADD(DAY, -1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) [WeekEnd]
      ,(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, -7 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)), 121) 
         + ' to ' 
       +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATEADD(DAY, -1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)), 121)) as Week
```

You cannot concatenate two date values in a column, you would need to convert them to a string and then concatenate them two values.